# Contour integral: Prove that the complex integral is equal to $-i\pi$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I want to prove that the complex integral $\int_{\gamma_{\varepsilon}}f(z)dz=-i\pi$. $f(z)=\frac{e^{iz^n}-1}{z^n}, \gamma_{\varepsilon}=\varepsilon e^{it}, t\in [0, \frac{\pi}{n}]$ where $n$ is fixed and we will take $\varepsilon\to 0$.

Context: The original problem is to prove that $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x^n)}{x^n}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$. I was able to complete part of this already.

What I have so far:

$\int_{\gamma_{\varepsilon}}f(z)dz=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\int_{0}^{\pi/n}i\frac{e^{i(\varepsilon e^{it})^n}-1}{(\varepsilon e^{it})^{n-1}}dt=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}i\int_{0}^{\pi/n}\varepsilon e^{it}-\frac{(\varepsilon e^{it})^{n+1}}{2}dt+\cdots=0$

Note: We have not covered residue calculus in class.